# Delete all class name that do not belong to class in case web browser c#

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have an HTML file that loads it into my webbrowser. in webbrowser I need to keep 1 class name "missing" and for other things I need to remove it from webbrowser. Anyone have any solution for this please advise me

```
 string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test", "*.html");
                foreach (string filename in filenames)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                    webBrowser1.DocumentText = richTextBox1.Text;
                    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
                    File.Delete(filename);
                    richTextBox1.Clear();
                }
 private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            {
                var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {
                    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "missing")
                    {
                       // need remove if classname = "missing" have!
                    }
              
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify an IEnumerable while also iterating on it. So you will either need to create a temporary list of all of the links that you want to remove, and then remove them after you are done iterating, or alternatively create a temporary list of all of the valid links, which you populate as you iterate through all of the links.